# Link to another java class

Tags: java

I have three classes in one folder:

**Waehrung** same as currency in Englisch!

```
public abstract class Waehrung {
    public abstract double dollarBetrag();
}
```

**USDollar**

```
public class UsDollar extends Waehrung {
    private double wert;

    public UsDollar(double wert){
        this.wert = wert;
    }

    public double dollarBetrag(){
        return wert;
    }
}
```

**Yen**

```
public class Yen extends Waehrung{

double wert;
private static double kurs;

public Yen(double wert){
    this.wert = wert;
}

public void setKurs(double kurs){
    this.kurs = kurs;
}

public double dollarBetrag(){
    return wert * kurs;
}
```

}

Now i worte another java Class that should make use of the others:
**Bank**

```
public class Bank {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Yen yen = new Yen(34);
        Yen.setKurse = (1.0/130);
        System.out.println(yen.dollarBetrag);
    }
}
```

My problem is that i do not understand how to link against the other classes! I made some tries with `import package` but it never compiled correctly! What do i wrong or how can i fix this!

Comment: Have you tried putting your classes in the same directory? Try doing that first in your IDE of choice.

Comment: Not sure why this is getting voted down, this is a perfectly valid question for a beginner.

Comment: @PeterBratton: maybe because of errors in class Bank that won't let him compile project correctly.

Comment: @Qiu Still not a good reason to downvote.  OP clearly shows effort in the problem.

Comment: @PeterBratton: agree. But i can't come up with anything better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you haven't put your classes in any package. Look here.

**com.currency.Waehrung**

```
package com.currency;
public abstract class Waehrung {
    public abstract double dollarBetrag();
}
```

**com.currency.USDollar class**

```
package com.currency;
public class UsDollar extends Waehrung {
    private double wert;

    public UsDollar(double wert){
        this.wert = wert;
    }

    public double dollarBetrag(){
        return wert;
    }
}
```

**com.currency.Yen**

```
package com.currency;
public class Yen extends Waehrung{

double wert;
private static double kurs;

public Yen(double wert){
    this.wert = wert;
}

public void setKurs(double kurs){
    this.kurs = kurs;
}

public double dollarBetrag(){
    return wert * kurs;
}
}
```

Now you've put all those classes in `com.currency` package. That means you make sure that those class files (.class) files exist in the `com\currency` folder.

Now, you can write the class

```
import com.currency.*;
public class Bank {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Yen yen = new Yen(34);
        yen.setKurs(1.0/130);
        System.out.println(yen.dollarBetrag());
    }
}
```

Now you can directly use these classes. Make sure that the folders **com\currency** exist.

The errors you've written in `Bank` class are:

```
Yen.setKurse = (1.0/130);
System.out.println(yen.dollarBetrag);
```

In the first line, you used `Yen` which is class name. You should use `yen` which is reference because setKurs() is a method. Another error in the same line is that setKurs() is the method name and not an instance variable. So you should call setKurs() also, `setKurse` is wrong 'e' is a typo.

Next, `dollarBetrag` is a method, so you should `yen.dollarBetrag()`

Thank you :)

Comment: Do i have to put all of my stuff into a package?

Comment: Yes, if you wish. or else you can simply put all of your classes in a single directory so that you don't have to import anything and you don't also need the package line above! -- I forgot import com.currency.*, please see above.

Comment: Its all in the same directory!

Comment: But i always get this error: `rror: cannot find symbol
     Yen.setKurse = (1.0/130);
        ^` Thanks

Comment: You should call the method yen.setKurs(1.0/130); It is just a typo. Don't worry :)

Comment: Sprry but you said: put all of your classes in a single directory so that you don't have to import anything and you don't also need the package line above!

Comment: Where has the com/currency folder to be?

Comment: You can place it in the folder where your `Bank` class is. For example, if you place Bank class in `C:\test`, then you can place those classes in `C:\test\com\currency`

Comment: I followed your steps but now when i try to compile Yen: I get this error:  cannot find symbol
public class Yen extends Waehrung{

Comment: try compiling like this `javac com\currency\*.java` and let me know if it worked. or you directly compile the `Bank` class, it will compile others too.

Comment: Thanks! Seems like it does work from the command line but not with the tools of Sublime Text! Thank you very much for taking your time and helping me! I wish you a nice evening!

Comment: Same to you John Smith! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import them all:

```
import com.yourpackage.money.*;
```

If you mean keeping some form of reference to them all, I usually store them in a `Map` or `Array`. Helps having a `toString` implementation or some way to get the money's name for this storage.

```
Map<String, Waehrung> currency = new HashMap<>();

Waehrung[] money = new Waehrung[]{
    new Yen(),
    new Dollar()
    // etc...
}

for (Waehrung m : money) {
    currency.put(m.getName(), m);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the class are not in the same package then you have to use import statements should be like that

```
import yourpackageNameofYen.Yen;
import yourpackageNameofUsDollar.USDollar;
```

you have to put these two import statements below the package declaration of your third class Bank

for example like

```
Package a;
import yourpackageNameofYen.Yen;
    import yourpackageNameofUsDollar.USDollar;
public class Bank {
        public static void main(String[] args){
            Yen yen = new Yen(34);
            Yen.setKurse = (1.0/130);
            System.out.println(yen.dollarBetrag);
        }
    }
```